# My masonry won't load when using .imagesLoaded

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, masonry, imagesloaded

So before I added the `.imagesLoaded` to my script, my masonry was working but it would be overlapped since the images weren't loading before the masonry. So this is what my function looks like:

```
function portfolio_masonry() {
wp_register_script( 'jquery_masonry', '/wp-content/themes/blankslate/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', '/wp-content/themes/blankslate/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_masonry' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portfolio_masonry' );

function portfolio_add_masonry() { ?>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#main_content').imagesLoaded( function(){
      $('#main_content').masonry();
  });
  });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'portfolio_add_masonry' );
```

Should I use the `pkgd.js` vs the `pkgd.min.js`?

Comment: Isn't `imagesloaded` a separate thing to `masonry`?  Shouldn't you enqueue both scripts?  What error are you getting (anything in the browser's console)?  Either `.js` file should do; unless you're planning on debugging or changing the code, use the `min` version - it's the one you should use in production

Comment: Sorry, just saw you're trying to enqueue both scripts in one command.  I don't think you can do that.  Split them out - one register and one enqueue per `.js` file

Comment: I tried it that way first. It didnt work though.

Comment: So when you put it back that way (because it won't work how you have it), what error are you getting (in the browser's console)?